# Deleting rows with NSFetchedResultController no object at index

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to delete rows from a TableView with a NSFetchedResultController, i've read many examples on how to do this and i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I need help on this one.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 1 in section at index 0'
```

This is my code for deleting:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Deleting object at row %d", indexPath.row);

    // DeleteObject
    NSManagedObject *objToDelete = (NSManagedObject*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Delete
    [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:objToDelete];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"DeleteRow caused : %@", error);
    }
}
```

This is my fetchController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {


    AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Dagbok" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"header" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:40];
    [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"relationship", nil]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSArray *matchingdata = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];


    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

This is my ObjectChanged

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {


    UITableView *tableView = _tabell;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(VallaDagbokCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have eliminated the lazy loading of the fetched results controller. It is therefore not clear when exactly the fetch request in the FRC getter is being executed. It looks like this happens *before* the row is deleted by the delegate methods.

Try repairing your FRC getter by reinserting the original lazy loading code snippet:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```